# Comment from start of file to a pattern matched line using sed

Tags: sed, gvim

I search a pattern, say 'START OF ARAMBOL' and it is matched in a file. Now I would like to comment every line from the line no 1 to the current matched pattern line no. I have to do it for more than 200 files.

I can do this using perl too but is there any good sed method to do so.

Thanks

Comment: Please be specific about what constitutes a comment in the context of your files (C-style comment? C++ style? leading `#` or `%`?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a one-liner to demonstrate the concept :

```
echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nPATTERN\nd\ne\nf' | sed '0,/PATTERN/ s/^/#/'
```

You just have to adapt to your context :

- as for the 'PATTERN'
- I assumed '#' as the commenting character
- and regarding how you can apply this to all your files. If they all are 'fileXXX.txt', you can run : `sed -i '0,/PATTERN/ s/^/#/' file*txt`

Comment: I would stress the assumption (actually reasonable, looking at the question) that the `PATTERN` is found in each file. This solution will comment any line in files in which `PATTERN` is not found.

Comment: The answer assumes GNU sed.

Answer (score 1):

Your question asks about `sed` but includes the `gvim` tag, so here is an `ed`/`ex` answer:

```
ed file <<EOF
0,/"$pattern"/s/^/"$comment_char"/
wq
EOF
```

That it looks remarkably like the `sed` answer is because `sed` and `ex` descend from `ed`